# How to get all classes and methods name from java libraray /apk etc

Tags: jar

please let me know how to extract the all the class name / method name from jar file/apk. Pardon me if teh similar questions ask already.

I am interested in any library that that java/c#  provides insted of some open source/3rd party software's.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the .jar file. A set of class files are obtained. Use cavaj decompiler to interpret the .class files.